# Injecting DI service on a extension method

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, extension-methods

I'm trying to get the `IStringLocalizer` service instance inside a extension method, is it possible? Any suggestions on how should I inject it?

My goal here is to translate a type using its name as convention.

```
public static class I18nExtensions
{

    private IStringLocalizer _localizer; // <<< How to inject it?

    public static string GetName(this Type type)
    {
        return _localizer[type.Name].Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are some ugly tricks that could work https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/294

Comment: I would argue that your extension method should be a service of its own (`ITypeNameLocalizer`) because it has a dependency. Reserve extension methods *only* for simple logic that is unlikely to change and will never have dependencies.

Comment: +10 for @NightOwl888.

Comment: Note if you want to use DI in an HTML helper, you could do something like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44321214/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following [@NightOwl888 comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235948/injecting-di-service-on-a-extension-method?noredirect=1#comment71635070_42235948) I was in the wrong path, I ended up creating the following service:

```
public class TypeNameLocalizer : ITypeNameLocalizer
{
    private IStringLocalizer localizer;

    public TypeNameLocalizer(IStringLocalizer<Entities> localizer) 
    {
        this.localizer = localizer;
    }
    public string this[Type type] 
    { 
        get
        {
            return localizer[type.Name];
        }
    }
}
```

Credit: @NightOwl888

Answer (score 5):

Why not just pass the `IStringLocalizer` as a parameter:

```
public static string GetName(this Type type, IStringLocalizer localizer)
{
    return localizer[type.Name].Value;
}
```

The purpose of extension methods is to *extend* behavior of objects. It seems to me that is what you're trying to do here.

Comment: because you will need to pass the interface as a parameter wherever you want to use the extension method.