# Dependency Injection in HtmlHelper extension method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

I want to implement property renderers as handlers. I am using Autofac as a DI container in the app. How can I get objects implementing IPropertyHandler in HtmlHelper extension without using globally accessible container (service location)? Is it a way to register own HtmlHelper in Autofac? Maybe MVC framework provide another way?

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions {
    public static MvcHtmlString Editor(this HtmlHelper html, object model) {
        return new Renderer(new List<IPropertyHandler>() /*Where to get these objects?*/ ).Render(html, model);
    }
}

public class Renderer {
    private readonly ICollection<IPropertyHandler> _propertyRenderers;

    public Renderer(ICollection<IPropertyHandler> propertyRenderers) {
        _propertyRenderers = propertyRenderers;
    }

    public MvcHtmlString Render(HtmlHelper html, object model) {
        var result = "";
        foreach(var prop in model.GetType().GetProperties()) {
            var renderers = _propertyRenderers.OrderBy(b => b.Order);
            //impl
        }
        return new MvcHtmlString(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, MVC 5 doesn't provide a way to do this. But that doesn't mean you can't wire up your own solution.

> MVC Core now uses *view components* that are DI friendly, so you don't have to jump through so many hoops.

As per the article [DI Friendly Framework by Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/), you can make a factory interface for your HTML helper that can be used to instantiate it with its dependencies.

### DefaultRendererFactory

First there is a default factory that provides the logical default behavior (whatever that is).

```
public interface IRendererFactory
{
    IRenderer Create();
    void Release(IRenderer renderer);
}

public class DefaultRendererFactory : IRendererFactory
{
    public virtual IRenderer Create()
    {
        return new Renderer(new IPropertyHandler[] { new DefaultPropertyHandler1(), DefaultPropertyHandler2() });
    }
    
    public virtual void Release(IRenderer renderer)
    {
        if (renderer is IDisposable disposable)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

You may wish to make this default factory smarter or even use a fluent builder to supply its dependencies as per the other article [DI Friendly Library](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library) so it is more flexible without using a DI container.

### IRenderer

Then we use an abstraction for `Renderer`, `IRenderer` so it can be swapped easily and/or provided via DI.

```
public interface IRenderer
{
    MvcHtmlString Render(HtmlHelper html, object model);
}

public class Renderer : IRenderer
{
    private readonly ICollection<IPropertyHandler> _propertyRenderers;

    public Renderer(ICollection<IPropertyHandler> propertyRenderers) 
    {
        _propertyRenderers = propertyRenderers;
    }

    public MvcHtmlString Render(HtmlHelper html, object model) 
    {
        var result = "";
        foreach(var prop in model.GetType().GetProperties()) 
        {
            var renderers = _propertyRenderers.OrderBy(b => b.Order);
            //impl
        }
        return new MvcHtmlString(result);
    }
}
```

### Factory Registration

Next, we provide a hook to register the factory. Since the HTML helper is a static extension method, the only option is to make a static field with a static property or method to set it. Its always good practice to make a getter as well in case there is a need to use a decorator pattern on the factory.

```
public interface IRendererFactory
{
    IRenderer Create();
    void Release(IRenderer renderer);
}

public static class HtmlHelperExtensions {
    private static IRendererFactory rendererFactory = new DefaultRendererFactory();
    
    public static IRendererFactory RendererFactory
    {
        get => rendererFactory;
        set => rendererFactory = value;
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString Editor(this HtmlHelper html, object model) {
        var renderer = rendererFactory.Create();
        try
        {
            return renderer.Render(html, model);
        }
        finally
        {
            rendererFactory.Release(renderer);
        }
    }
}
```

You could provide some logical place to register all of your factories statically, if that makes more sense for the app. But there will basically need to be a factory per HTML helper to adhere to the SRP. If you try to generalize, you are basically back to a service locator.

### AutofacRendererFactory

Now that all of the pieces are in place, this is how you would slip Autofac into the equation. You will need a custom `IRendererFactory` that you will make *part of your composition root* that is specific to Autofac.

```
public class AutofacRendererFactory : IRendererFactory
{
    private readonly Autofac.IContainer container;

    public AutofacRendererFactory(Autofac.IContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container ?? new ArgumentNullException(nameof(container));
    }

    public IRenderer Create()
    {
        return this.container.Resolve(typeof(IRenderer));
    }
    
    public void Release(IRenderer renderer)
    {
        // allow autofac to release dependencies using lifetime management
    }
}
```

Next, you need to add the type mappings for `IRenderer` and its dependencies to Autofac.

Last but not least, you will need to add a line to your application startup after creating the Autofac container to resolve the renderer when it is needed by the application.

```
// Register all of your types with the builder
// ...
// ...
Autofac.IContainer container = builder.Build();
HtmlHelperExtensions.RendererFactory = new AutofacRendererFactory(container);
```