# Reading appsettings.json directly, or accessing IOptions<T> from an Extension method

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have an extension method which is used to read a particular claim from the current `ClaimsPrincipal`. But I also need to check this value against a list of items which I have in the `appsettings.json`.
I had this working by using a `ConfigurationBuilder()` to read the `appsettings` directly in much the same way as the startup does, although instead of using

```
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
```

as I do in the startup, I was using

```
.SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location))
```

Which although isn't pretty, works fine.
However, when the Unit tests are run none of the following get me to where the appsettings are

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

and I cannot see a way of getting the `IHostingEnvironment` or something similar into the extension method to read out the `appsettings`, or indeed to ditch the `ConfigurationBuilder()` and get at `IOptions` in the extension method, in such a way that the unit test and the running code will work correctly.

I assume there must be a way of doing this? Although I expect that I should simply not be trying at all and lift the check against the list of items into another class entirely...

Comment: Seems like you are fighting against DI with your extension methods. Is there any reason you can't pass the configuration as a parameter to your extension method?

Comment: not really if I'm honest, I think that may be the simplest option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting business logic that may **ever require dependencies** into static methods is not recommended. This makes it difficult to inject dependencies into them. Options are few:

1. Redesign the static method into a service so dependencies can be injected through the constructor. **(Recommended)**

---

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private readonly IOptions<FooOptions> optionsAccessor;
    public Foo(IOptions<FooOptions> optionsAccessor)
    {
        this.optionsAccessor = optionsAccessor ??
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(optionsAccessor));
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
         var x = this.optionsAccessor;

         // Same implementation as your static method
    }
}
```

2. Inject the dependencies as parameters of the extension method.

---

```
public static void DoSomething(this object o, IOptions<FooOptions> optionsAccessor)
{
    // Implementation
}
```

3. Redesign the static method to be a facade over an abstract factory [like this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44321214/).

Comment: thanks, I was hoping not to have to redo this as its only a particular implementation for our load balancing environment, but I guess there is no escape. thanks for your help